# wmi and vbscript to clear event logs on the remote server in windows 2003

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript

How can I use  wmi to clear event logs on the remote server in the same domain? Both the servers are windows 2003?
What VB script can I use to clear logs in windows 2003?
What powershell script can I use to clear logs in windows 2003?
Can I clear the event logs in windows 2003 server from windows 7 using winevtutil or powershell comamnd?
Both the machines are in the separate domain? I can map the files on windows 2003 server from windows 7 machine providing the admin accounts login?

Comment: You might want to start your research here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849789.aspx

Comment: This seems more like a system administration than a programming question to me, so it should've been asked on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\User>wmic nteventlog call /?

Method execution operations.
USAGE:

CALL <method name> [<actual paramlist>]
NOTE: <actual paramlist> ::= <actual param> | <actual param>,  <actual paramlist
>

The following alias verb(s)/method(s) are available:

Call                    [ In/Out ]Params&type                   Status
====                    =====================                   ======
BackupEventlog          [IN ]ArchiveFileName(STRING)            (null)

ClearEventlog           [IN ]ArchiveFileName(STRING)            (null)
```

So something like

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 nteventlog where filename='system' call ClearEventLog
```

is the command line version.

In VBS (& "." is the computer name. . means local computer. Use Names or IP addresses).

```
Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & ".")
Set logFile = WMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NTEventLogFile " & "Where LogFileName='System'")
For Each F in LogFile
    msgbox F.ClearEventLog
Next
```